# Вывод в MessageBox код нажатой клавиши

Tags: c++, winforms

Необходимо выводить в MessageBox код нажатой клавиши. Как выводить непосредственно прожатый символ клавиши мне известно (через keyChar), а как выводить код символа?
Спасибо за помощь.

Comment: `(int)keyChar`?